# Unable to detect active object interface in rest service

Tags: java, rest, jira, active-objects

My active object interface is as below :

```
package com.company.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities;
import java.util.Date;
import net.java.ao.Accessor;
import net.java.ao.Mutator;
import net.java.ao.Preload;
import net.java.ao.Entity;
import net.java.ao.schema.Table;

@Table("TaskData")
@Preload
public interface TaskData extends Entity {

@Accessor("issues")
String getIssues();

@Mutator("issues")
   void setIssues(String issues);

}
```

Now, My rest service class is as below:

```
package com.company.jira.plugin.REST;
import com.crawco.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities.IssuePlanning;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import net.java.ao.Query;
...


@Path("/message")
public class TasksDataRestResource {

@POST
@AnonymousAllowed
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/save/{start}/{end}/{issues}/{comments}/{startdatetime}")
public Response SaveTasksData(@PathParam("start") Date paramStart,@PathParam("end") Date     paramEnd,@PathParam("issues") String paramIssues,@PathParam("comments") String   paramComments,@PathParam("startdatetime") String startdatetime)
{

....
 ...
 ...  
**com.company.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities.TaskData pi = ao.executeInTransaction(new TransactionCallback() // (1)**           
{   
     @Override
     public com.company.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities.TaskData doInTransaction()
     {
        com.company.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities.TaskData pi = ao.create(com.company.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities.TaskData.class);

        pi.setIssues(issues);
                        ...
        logger.info("REST Service:before pi.save");
        pi.save();           
        logger.info("REST Service:after pi.save");          
        return pi;
     }
});

 return Response.ok(new .....).build();
    }
```

In above stuff, i have high lighted the line "** .... **" which raise me an error while execute "atlas-run", error is as below:

```
C:\atlas-projects\src\main\.....REST\TasksDataRestResource.java:[176,86] incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: com.company.jira.plugin.Reports.aoentities.TaskData
```

Can you suggest me what is wrong here ?

Also, file name is "TaskData.java" as same as it's activeobject interface name.
(in above stuff, i have given full qualify name for "TaskData" but not worked, before, i kept only "TaskData" and referred through imported namespace).

(using eclipse editor and atlas-sdk 4.1.4).

### NOTE:

one weird behavior is, it works for some times but not every time, Usually, whenever i get above error then, remove some spaces or lines in "TaskData" interface and rest service class then it gets work)

Answer (score 0):

you can clean the project after build maven package 
Project--->clean then select which project/plugin you want to clean and click on ok.
i think it may help you!!